# How to create a distribution of VSCode on MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

After forking vscode, I want to make sure my new code will work on cross-platform distributions. How do I create a distribution of vscode with my forked code?

I know vscode uses electron and have been looking through the docs but errors prevent me from using electron forge.